# Do I need a Firebase project to use Firebase App Check?

Tags: flutter, firebase, api, dart, firebase-app-check

I want to secure my own custom API for my Flutter app.
I came across Firebase App Check, but I do not want to use Firebase.

Can I use Firebase App Check without a Firebase project? It seems to like there is not Firebase involved. Only other app attestation services. https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/custom-resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need a Firebase project to use Firebase App Check?

Yes.

> It seems to like there is not Firebase involved. Only other app attestation services.

Firebase is not an attestation provider but it uses others providers and it's a bit easier to integrate those providers using Firebase SDK than directly using them. e.g `reCAPTCHA v3` for web apps.

Once you [integrate the Firebase App Check SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers) in your Flutter app, you'll have to get the App Check token using [`getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/custom-resource#send_app_check_tokens_with_backend_requests) and add it in your API request. Then you just need to [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend) in your backend using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).